# How to convert an unexpected exception into an assertion failure in NUnit test/Selenium/C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, nunit

I am a newbie and couldn't make out in the NUnit documentation. I think this link contains useful information:
https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/ThrowsConstraint.html

How to convert unexpected exception whether "element is not clickable", "click is intersepted" into  an assertion failure.

Without a convert, the [Retry] NUnit attribute does not restart failed tests on an unexpected exception.

test suite structure

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }

    ....

    [Test]
    [Retry(3)]
    public void voidName()
    {
       Assert.That(() =>
            {
                 var name = new className(driver);
                 name.methodName();
            }, 
            Throws.Nothing);
       
    }
    .....

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
            driver.Quit();
    }
```

test method structure

```
public void methodName()
        {
            ....
            ....
          if(result == true)
           {
              Assert.Pass();
           }
          else
           {
              Assert.Fail();
           }
       


        }
```

Regardless of whether Pass or Fail has a methodName, voidName returns failed

Answer (score 0):

Edit # 2:

In NUnit (or any unit testing framework) if a unit test passes any assertions, the program continues from that point normally. If it fails an Assertion, the entire unit test fails at that point.

So it seems that you need to debug your code as it is not working as you expect. Your unit test is failing because it is encountering the `Assert.Fail()` in your logic.

That being said, I don't think you should place your Assertions within the logic of your code. Instead, you should throw exceptions, and **keep Assert statements only in your unit tests**. Otherwise, such issues will be difficult to avoid.

```cs
public void methodName()
{
    ....
    ....
    if(result == true)
    { 
        // No need to call assert statements here
    }
    else
    {
        throw new System.Exception("Write your custom error message here.");
    }
    ....
}
```

Edit # 1:

Okay, now that you have shared your code, You can do as shown as Charlie mentioned

```cs
[Test] 
[Retry(3)] 
public void DepositFoOpen() 
{
    Assert.That(
        () => 
        { 
            var MMFO = new MMFO_Tests_Lib.DepositFO(driver);
            MMFO.DepositFoOpen();
        }, Throws.Nothing); 
}
```

or if you want to use try-catch block as I mentioned:

```cs
[Test] 
[Retry(3)] 
public void DepositFoOpen() 
{
    try
    {
        var MMFO = new MMFO_Tests_Lib.DepositFO(driver);
        MMFO.DepositFoOpen();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. When writing "Assert.Fail", the test fails at the point where this method is written. Where exceptions might occur, I don't know. Therefore, any exception must be converted to assertion failure.

Comment: @Norlerion Okay, Then I guess What Charlie answered is exactly what you're looking for. Otherwise, you can use my answer by making a try-catch block, calling your test method in the try block, and calling the `Assert.Fail()` in the catch block.

Comment: Can you tell me where and how should I write what Charlie suggested?

Comment: @Norlerion In your unit test, write `Assert.That(() => SomeMethod(), Throws.Nothing);` where `SomeMethod()` is the method you want to fail on throwing exception

Comment: My code has the structure:                                                                                            [Test]
[Retry(3)]
        public void methodName()
        {
            var name = new class.unitTest(driver);
            name.unitTest();
            Assert.That(() =>  name.unitTest(), Throws.Nothing);
        }                                                                                                                                                             But it still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry that I did not reply for a while. I am from Ukraine and I have big problems with electricity and internet. Thanks for the suggested options. Both methods work. But if there is a asserture at the end of the test method, then both methods for some reason consider that the test has failed. For example:                         if (result == true)
            { Assert.Pass();  }
            else  {Assert.Fail(); }. Regardless of whether it is a pass or a fail, the test is considered a failure. Can you suggest what can be done?

Comment: @Norlerion No apologies needed. Hope you are safe. As for your question, I'm not sure if I understood it correctly. Can you edit your question and in the post itself? The code you've shared `if (result == true) { Assert.Pass(); } else {Assert.Fail(); }`, this is the method for which you wish to see if its throwing exceptions or not?

Comment: @Norlerion if you're putting a unit test within a unit test, I would say you're doing this incorrectly. If your inner unit test invokes `Assert.Fail()`, it will immediately end the entire unit test. You should change this approach of having a unit test within a unit test. Unit test should not depend on other unit test(unless you're doing an integration test), and should only check for your project's logic/functionality.

Comment: i added changes to the post

Comment: @Norlerion I have updated my answer. Let me know if this works as you intended.

Comment: Thank you. This method helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you want the `ThrowsNothingConstraint`

```
Assert.That(() => SomeMethod(), Throws.Nothing);
```

UPDATE: I'd give you more detail if your question had details. :-)

All I know from your question is that some method of yours causes an exception to be thrown. I called that method "SomeMethod" 'cause that's all I know. I wrapped it in an Assert so that the error would be for the specific line of code, which causes the exception.

If you **don't** know which method call causes the exception, then you should figure it out. Most likely, it's some call you make to Selenium.

Comment: Can you tell me where I should write this line? I tried to write it at the end of the test method and inside the attribute [test]. And it doesn't work.

Comment: See the update I made to the answer. If you want specific details, please provide your own specific details in the question itself. General questions can only get general answers. In any case, the assert should go wherever you are calling the method, which causes an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested option. But if there is a asserture at the end of the test method, then ur method for some reason consider that the test has failed. For example: if (result == true) { Assert.Pass(); } else {Assert.Fail(); }. Regardless of whether it is a pass or a fail, the test is considered a failure. Can you suggest what can be done?

Comment: You should not use Assert.Pass in this situation because Assert.Pass throws an exception in order to stop the rest of the test. There is no reason to ever use it at the end of a method. Instead, just let the test pass without asserting. Hint: it's inadvisable to mix your own error processing using Pass and Fail with NUnit's internal processing. Best to rely entirely on NUnit's handling of errors unless you have a thorough knowledge of how NUnit works internally. This is true of any kind of framework if you don't have internal knowledge.